# Wordpress google mobile optimalisation

Tags: wordpress, optimization, mobile

Since google updated their way of scoring mobile I have trouble to optimise my websites.

I want to know what am I doing wrong and what should be done to existing sites to make the score higher. Its easy to get 95-100 on desktop but on same site on mobile will be 25...

Before someone says to follow suggestions by insights then I will say that I do and I managed to remove most of them - worst thing is that the score didn't move at all. This is the biggest struggle I have, it seems that whatever I do it wont be good enough...

I followed this guide https://kinsta.com/blog/google-pagespeed-insights/ + some of my own solutions.

Is there anyone that has any good tips or permanent solution for this issue?

[Google Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrULf.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the insights report for your website?

Comment: Edited main post - link at the bottom

Comment: This question is blatantly off topic for SO - it has nothing to do with programming.  Flagging to close.

Comment: @JustinR. Can you remind me since when optimisation is not programming?

Comment: Website optimization is a collection of strategies to reduce your site load time.  This typically includes processes such as minification, implementing a CDN, changing caching times, and server administration.  You generally aren't writing any new code to do anything.  Explain to me otherwise how it's programming.

Answer (score 0):

As evident from your Page Speed Insights report, the main factor responsible for your low score is images. The solution to this is using RESPONSIVE IMAGES, which will drastically improve the speed of your website on mobile. What it basically means is that, you'll have to keep different sizes of the same image available for the browser and browser will decide which version of the image is suited on a particular resolution.

1) Here's everything you need to know about Responsive Images --> [Responsive Image (CSS Tricks)](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)

2) You have to shift the `<link href=".." .../>` and `<script>` tags from top of the page to the bottom of the page, just after the `<body>` tag. This will fix the `Eliminate render blocking resources issue.

3) You can use [Javascript Minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/) to minify your JS. Just paste your existing JS code inside the `Input Javascript` box on the website and click **MINIFY**

Also, cache policy is also one of the factors, bringing your score down. An efficient Cache policy will make browsers, load your website faster, after the first load. Cache handling is server specific, its different for Apache, Express etc.

Comment: Thanks, I read the google guide lines too. Wonder how would you go about changing links in plugins etc.

Comment: What platform are you using? Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, it is Wordpress and there is no simple solution to get everything right. I got rid of a lot of issues thrown by google insights and score barley moved...

Comment: For your `images` problem which probably is the main cause, you may want to look at this : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/automate-your-responsive-images-with-mobify-js/  Also, do upvote my answer if it was of any use to you.